# Automate Commission Field For Each Opportunity

Tags: apex, trigger, opportunity, automation, force

guys I am a beginner to apex coding in salesforce. I want a guide on how to automate a commission's field for every opportunity that I have. However, there are factors to calculating the commission; the lead source and the markup percentage. I don't want the answer but I would like a guide to how I would go about doing this. I know how to create a new field, but I need to have conditional statements for that field so if the opportunity is a certain lead then it will calculate it that certain way. I don't know if the conditional statements will go in a field or do I have to create a trigger?

Comment: one thing to consider is whether the resulting commission can be overridden by a/the user.

Answer (score 0):

The requirement sounds basic enough that you might be able to do this in a formula field - check out https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Formulas for a starting reference.

If the calculation is going to be based solely off two fields on the Opportunity, then this is probably the way to go. If other factors are at play here, then maybe not.

I will say that I love that you're thinking of this already. It's so easy for a developer to just say "oh I'll just write a trigger or code to do this." When developing in Salesforce, always ask first: "Can I do this without writing Apex?"

Comment: Thank you very much, I figured it out and everything works fine.  I appreciate the help!